# Image processing-YUV to Rgb

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Why does one convert from YUV to RGB , what is the advantage in image processing using matlab of doing such a conversion. I know the answer partially that Y is the light component which gets eliminated in RGB format? what is the basis of such conversions?

Comment: please note that it's yuv, not yuy

Comment: RGB allows us to perceptually understand the images much better... and it's the format that's directly taken off of a CCD camera for example.  RGB is also used as the base colour space to go to other colour spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what you could have  easily found on the internet:

YUV was introduced when colour tvs came up. there should be minimum interference with existing monochrome tvs. so they added color information uv to the luminance signal y.

Due to the way digital colour images are captured (using red, green or blue pass-filtered pixels) the native colour space for digital images is RGB.
Modern displays also use red, green and blue pixels.
For printing you will find YMCK colour space as printing.

Nowadays RGB is the default colour space in digital image processing as we usually process the raw image information. you won't find many algorithms that can handle YUV images directly.